# laravel hasMany on two columns

Tags: php, laravel

hi im using laravel 7 i've the relation in the user model called get_journal_entry_lines

```
public function get_journal_entry_lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Journal_entry_line','user_id','id')->orderBy('date','asc');
}
```

sometimes the user in column called `user_id` and sometimes on other column called `partner_id`
so is it possable to do something like this in laravel

```
public function get_journal_entry_lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Journal_entry_line','user_id','id')->orderBy('date','asc')->orWhere('partner_id','=','id');
}
```

get `Journal_entry_line` from columns `user_id` and `partner_id` at same relation .

Comment: So what you're trying to do is to get different journal entries based on the user_id or partner_id?

Comment: i need on both columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just create 2 different relations?

For example, you could use the one below for your users:

```
public function get_journal_entry_lines_for_users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Journal_entry_line','user_id','id')->orderBy('date','asc')->orWhere('partner_id','=','id');
}
```

and this one for your partners:

```
public function get_journal_entry_lines_for_partners()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Journal_entry_line','partner_id','id')->orderBy('date','asc');
}
```

Comment: i can but i need to Marriage them in one relation